# Datagrid para textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-basic-6

Boas Pessoal.

Eu tenho uma `DataGridView` onde tenho o campo `id`. O `id` neste momento está preenchido com 10 valores, ou seja, o último número a aparecer na minha `DataGridView` é o número "10", e quero ter uma `TextBox` onde apareça automaticamente o número seguinte (neste caso seria o número "11"), e depois de inserido o número "11" na grelha apareceria o "12".

Estou a usar o **Visual Basic** e a minha base de dados está em **SQL Server**.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi corretamente, o que você deseja pode ser obtido manipulando o evento **DefaultValuesNeeded**:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DefaultValuesNeeded
    e.Row.Cells(0).Value = e.Row.Index + 1
End Sub
```